# UltraWinGrid causes OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm working in a C# desktop software based on .NET 3.5.

I've a large UltraWinGrid object with 16000 rows and 401 columns. Iterating over all of the cells using the code below:

```
UltraGridRow currentrow = _grid.GetRow(ChildRow.First);
for (int r = 0; r < _grid.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < currentrow.Cells.Count; c++)
    {
        // Do stuff
```

The code above used to work on Infragistics 3.x. After we've upgraded the Infragistics DLL to 12.1, it starts to throw OutOfMemoryException exception. I've gone through [this guideline](http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wingrid-memory-usage), but it doesn't apply to my case as I need to access many other properties of the cells other than the value.

How to safely iterate over all cells without throwing OutOfMemoryException in UltraWinGrid? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thats 6416000 operations, which a hell of a lot. You may want to look at moving your process out of the UI into a background thread or database.

Comment: I wish I could. This software is written more than a decade ago and we're not allowed to make that big change between releases.

Comment: That sounds familiar. I'm guessing it wasn't desgined to handle that much data originally. 
Is it possible to defer some of the operations so that you are only processing the visible rows, then when the user scrolls process some more?
What is happening in //Do stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, not tested thoroughly though. Each cells of the row of the table can be deallocated once the processing of that row is done via [DeallocateCells()](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow~DeallocateCells.html).